# is it possible to assign a position in a hashtable that hasn't been created yet?

Tags: android, hashtable

In short, I want to assign an arrayList to a position in the hashtable that hasn't been created.

As an example let's say that my hashtable has something in it's 1st position, but I need to put something in its 4th position. When I try this now, it doesn't seem possible as it only works if I put values in the 2nd and 3rd positions before I assign the 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashTable maintain mapping not sequence, you will put value along with key, but not at specified index like 1,2 or 4. for indexed collection use list or justify reason of using hashtable with value at index .